# Anagram of an anagram

Tags: wordplay, anagram

> My anagram's anagram is a furious lady.
>   My anagram's anagram is a comic military force.
>   My anagram's anagram is to sell weapons to a flamboyant guy.

What are we anagramming?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are anagramming

> "My anagram"

**FULL** explanation:

`My anagram's anagram is a furious lady.`

> My anagram ~ angry ma'am(by me) /mama (thanks @Stiv)

`My anagram's anagram is a comic military force.`

> My anagram ~ manga army (thanks @MrPie in my chatroom) (original answer was “an mag army”, but realised this was much better)

`My anagram's anagram is to sell weapons to a flamboyant guy.`

> My anagram ~ arm gay man (thanks @Stiv)

Comment: Well, that didn't take long. Everything's correct.

Comment: There was some contentious commentary on how this answer developed. Comments are not for extended discussion (and this sort of discussion in particular should really be done on our Meta).  The conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95946/discussion-on-answer-by-omega-krypton-anagram-of-an-anagram).